# Why does WAMP occassionally serve garbage pages?

Tags: php, wamp

I have a localhost webpage that occasionally splits out broken HTML midway through the page. This will also happen with images, (although I suspect because they are very large in size 1200x2000px)

But this normally will happen during a database `while ($data=mysql_fetch_contents($arr))` loop.

Has anyone seen this before and what did you do to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer was a buffer overflow issue.

Placing this code at the end of each while loop:

```
@ob_flush();
```

Fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the PHP script may be timing out in the middle of execution, that is, run for longer than is allowed.

If the script is expected to run for a long time, you could try changing how long the script is allowed to run with the [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) function, or the [`max_execution_time`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) directive in `php.ini`.